# Explanation on Android's onResume and onPause method

Tags: android, events, methods, resume

I am starting Android Programming!

Can anyone give me a simple explanation about Android's onResume onPause event?

When does it occur and when does the activity get destroyed and free memory? Thanks!

Comment: you can easily find it in books or or google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application will be destroyed upon the onDestroy() method; this is generally called the last activity in your application has left the stack.

onPause() and onResume() I believe are called when another activity is placed on top of the current activity in the stack - onPause() would be called once said activity loses focus, and onResume() would be called once it gains focus again.

The below image should explain things better. Good luck!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

when lauch: onCreate onStart onResume

when press HOME: onPause onStop

when restart through menu(or lastest shortcut): onRestart onStart onResume

when press BACK: onPause onStop onDestory

when change orientation:onPause onStop onDestory then onCreate onStart onResume

watch the Activity life circle for more details

It's recommend to save status in onPause